# Constraint-based layouts for GUIs

Tags: reference-request, constraint-satisfaction, user-interface

The VPRI institut founded by Alan Kay has some papers on constraint-based  layouts for GUIs based on constraint solving.

For instance:

- [Wallingford: Toward a Constraint Reactive Programming Language](http://www.vpri.org/pdf/tr2016001_wallingford.pdf) by Alan Borning (2016)
- [A Report on KScript and KSWorld](http://www.vpri.org/pdf/rn2012001_kscript.pdf) by Yoshiki Ohshima, Bert Freudenberg, Aran Lunzer and Ted Kaehler (2012)

Further papers by Alan Borning and others include:

- [Scwm: An Extensible Constraint-Enabled Window Manager](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix01/freenix01/full_papers/badros/badros_html/) by Greg J. Badros, Jeffrey Nichols and Alan Borning
- [Constraint Solving for Beautiful User Interfaces](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~lutteroth/publications/ZeidlerLutterothWeber2012-LayoutAesthetics.pdf):How Solving Strategies Support Layout Aesthetics by Zeidler, Lutteroth and Weber (2012)

Are there other groups working on constraint-based layouts for GUIs?

Comment: Try looking at people who cite these papers.